# Get implementations off a MapBinder in Guice

Tags: java, guice

Basically I want to understand how the MapBinder works. I tried to search for example but couldn't find one that satisfied me. Before my question, here is some of my setup.

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    MapBinder<String, MyInterface> binder = MapBinder.newMapBinder(.....);
    binder.addBinding("one", One.class);
    binder.addBinding("two", Two.class);
  }

}

public class EntryPoint {
  @Inject
  Map<String, MyInterface> myMap;

  public void start() {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());
    Two two = myMap.get("two");
    //Use two here.
  }
}
```

How do the bindings get injected to `myMap`? I feel like I am not using it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't causing your `EntryPoint` to be injected anywhere. You want to do

```
EntryPoint ep = injector.getInstance(EntryPoint.class);
```

or if that won't work,

```
injector.injectMembers(this);
```

from within `EntryPoint`.